# Missing logging in Elasticsearch, when doing MLT (more like this) query

Tags: logging, elasticsearch, morelikethis

I am using **more like this** query in **ElasticSearch** and the problem is, that this query doesn't appear on the log file for some reason. I've tried several logging levels like DEBUG, INFO, but that didn't give me a solution.

**ElasticSearch** wiki is also silent about logging this type of query.

**logging.yml**

```
# you can override this using by setting a system property, for example -Des.logger.level=DEBUG
es.logger.level: DEBUG
rootLogger: ${es.logger.level}, console, file
logger:
  # log action execution errors for easier debugging
  action: DEBUG
  # reduce the logging for aws, too much is logged under the default INFO
  com.amazonaws: WARN

  # gateway
  #gateway: DEBUG
  #index.gateway: DEBUG

  # peer shard recovery
  #indices.recovery: DEBUG

  # discovery
  #discovery: TRACE

  index.search.slowlog: TRACE, index_search_slow_log_file
  index.indexing.slowlog: TRACE, index_indexing_slow_log_file

additivity:
  index.search.slowlog: false
  index.indexing.slowlog: false

appender:
  console:
    type: console
    layout:
      type: consolePattern
      conversionPattern: "[%d{ISO8601}][%-5p][%-25c{2}] %m%n"

  file:
    type: dailyRollingFile
    file: ${path.logs}/${cluster.name}.log
    datePattern: "'.'yyyy-MM-dd"
    layout:
      type: pattern
      conversionPattern: "[%d{ISO8601}][%-5p][%-25c{2}] %m%n"

  index_search_slow_log_file:
    type: dailyRollingFile
    file: ${path.logs}/${cluster.name}_index_search_slowlog.log
    datePattern: "'.'yyyy-MM-dd"
    layout:
      type: pattern
      conversionPattern: "[%d{ISO8601}][%-5p][%-25c{2}] %m%n"

  index_indexing_slow_log_file:
    type: dailyRollingFile
    file: ${path.logs}/${cluster.name}_index_indexing_slowlog.log
    datePattern: "'.'yyyy-MM-dd"
    layout:
      type: pattern
      conversionPattern: "[%d{ISO8601}][%-5p][%-25c{2}] %m%n"
```

Comment: Do you simply want to see the generated query in the log file? What info do you need to be logged exactly?

Comment: @Val, logging query input or produced query is enough, cause right now i don't even get the event about mlt query

Comment: Ok, then I think you'll find something useful in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to see the `more_like_this` query that the ES server receives, you can do so by making sure it is sinked to the [slow log file](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-slowlog.html#search-slow-log). To achieve this, you simply need to tweak your `elasticsearch.yml` config file (at the end) like this. Uncomment the following line and change the value to something very low, like `1ms`:

```
index.search.slowlog.threshold.query.trace: 1ms
```

After restarting your ES server, the effect of this is that every query your ES server receives will be logged in the slow log file, including your `more_like_this` query.

Comment: to be honest, looks like a workaround or usage of slow log feature in a wrong way. Don't look like that to you?

Comment: The thing is, if you look at the source code, you'll see that nothing is logged query-wise except if you ask for it, so even if this file is called **slow**log, it can be used to dump any query whether slow or fast. The **slow** log would not be configurable at all if it was intended just for logging slow queries.

Comment: Have you tried and does it yield the results you expect?

Comment: yes, it's working for me, thank you, I still disagree with this mechanism - it's clear misuse of functionality, that should find slow queries (at least by the name), but looks like only working solution

Comment: I think this feature started out as a real "slow log" feature, but in the end proved useful for many other use cases, hence its configurability. Anyhow, I'll update this answer if I ever find a way to do differently.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is probably too fast to be logged in the slow log file. Lower the slow log threshold either in the `elasticsearch.yml` file or in the index settings. You can even use a 0ms threshold to log every query. See [Slow Log reference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-slowlog.html) and [Logging Secrets blog post](https://www.elastic.co/blog/elasticsearch-logging-secrets) for more information.

Comment: yes, you're right, but also, im expecting to have mechanism for querying all mlt queries, not fast or slow ones.